# After each times click an increasing number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want after each times click value `2011` an increasing number, how is it?

**[Example:](http://jsfiddle.net/6ydUR/1/)**

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var num = '2011';
    var out = num ++1;
    alert(num); // i want this output: 2012
});
```

Comment: FYI, you're defining `num` as a string because of the quotes.  Also, The ++ operator doesn't have anything else with it (like a 1).  ++ Means incremenmt, or "add one to the value".

Comment: `var out = num ++1;` is an invalid statement. Either use: `var out = ++num;`, `var out = num = num + +1;`, `var out = num = num + 1`. Using `var out = num++;` won't produce the desired result, because `num++` returns the value of `num` before the incremental expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var num = 2011;
$('button').click(function() {
    num++;
    alert(num); // i want this output: 2012
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var num = '2011';
$('button').click(function() {
    num++;
    alert(num); // i want this output: 2012
});
```

Comment: `num` would be globally declared if this code was run within a local scope, because of a missing `var ` prefix.

Comment: That was the idea. Didn't know how deep the OP wants the function.

Comment: No matter how "deep" the OP goes, the scope will cause the piece of function to work. It's a good practice to always specify `var`, unless explicitly stated otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var num = '2011';
$('button').click(function() {
    var out = num++;
    alert(num);
});
```

- `var num` must be outside of the function, otherwise it will be 2011 again every time the function is run.
- `num++1` should be `num++`.

Comment: Just for the readers at home, if you *did* want to actually use the out variable (since you're declaring it), then you would need to change the code to use the prefix increment operator. Like this:

var out = ++num;
alert(out);